# iSeries: SQLRPGLE How to call a procedure for each record in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Within an SQLRPGLE program I need to run an insert into statement to copy some records to another file having copied records assigned a new record ID.
To do so I followed these steps:

1) Prototype a procedure to get a new record ID each time is called

```
    D ri_box12        PR            13S 0
    D   wkFileName                  10A   Value
```

2) Execute a dynamic SQL statement

```
    C                   EVAL      SQL_STM='insert into PGMR46/STD05GR0F'
    C                                    +' (select CART, CARV, '
    C                                    +%char(ri_box12('STD05GR0F'))
    C                                    +'  from arasso0f)'
    C/EXEC SQL
    C+ execute immediate :SQL_STM
    C/END-EXEC
```

3) Define ri_box12 procedure

```
    P ri_box12        B
    D ri_box12        PI            13S 0
    D   wkFileName                  10A   Value
    D   wkID          S             13S 0
    C                   DO

    ** ...some instructions to give wkID a value
    C                   ENDDO
    C                   Return    wkID
    P                 E
```

The point is that ri_box12 is called only once, so all copied records have the same ID; multiple runs of the program again copy all records with a new record ID.

What did I do wrong or what am I missing?

Than you very much

Comment: I've just realised that the way I did it is wrong because my procedure is called outside SQL statement. So, I dont' know exactly how to define an internal SQLRPGLE procedure that can be called within an SQL statement, if possible. Otherwise, I guess I should do something different.  Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you don't need to use dynamic SQL here.  Static SQL would work and static SQL is prefered for security and performance reasons.

```
/free    
 exec SQL
   insert into PGMR46/STD05GR0F
     select CART, CARV, ri_box12('STD05GR0F')
     from arasso0f
 end-exec;
```

However, in order for the CALL of the RPGLE function to work, you are missing one piece.

You have to defined what's known as an external User Defined Function (UDF).  This is a one time step. You're basically informing the SQL query engine that the RPGLE function exists and what it's interface looks like.

You usually wouldn't want the `INSERT` statement above in the same program as the `ri_box12()` function.  Normally you'd have a process like so

1. create a *SRVPGM (or *PGM) containing ri_box12()
2. create UDF pointing to ri_box12()
3. create program/stored procedure that uses the UDF

Step 3 is the program containing your `INSERT` SQL statement.

Step 2 is simply running a SQL statement that will look like so:

```
create function ri_box12(
  filename char(10)
  ) returns numeric(13,0)
  language RPGLE
  parameter style general
  returns null on null input
  program type sub
  external name 'MYSRVPGM(RIBOX_12)';
```

There's lots of other settings you can/should specify for the function.  Take a look at the [CREATE FUNCTION (External Scalar)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcfsce.htm) section of the SQL reference manual.

I'd also highly recommend reading the [External Procedures, Triggers, and User-Defined Functions on IBM DB2 for i Redbook](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246503.html?Open)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Though I was reading SQL Reference Redbook, your words helped me put the pieces altogether. I had hoped there was a way to do it without creating a UDF function for my external program.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the function ri_box12 from the OP does, but if merely a sequential number, then there is the SQL SEQUENCE as possible means for achieving that effect; see the following scripted SQL for an example:

```
drop   table qtemp.nbrs ;                        
drop   table qtemp.junk ;                        
drop sequence myseq ;                            
create table qtemp.nbrs (n int)         ;        
insert into  qtemp.nbrs values(10), (20), (30) ; 
create table qtemp.junk (s int, i int)  ;        
create sequence myseq as integer start with 1  ; 
insert into  qtemp.junk                          
 select next value for myseq, n from qtemp.nbrs ;
select * from qtemp.junk
; -- report from the above SELECT query follows:
        S               I
        1              10
        2              20
        3              30
```

[IBM i 7.2->Database->Reference->SQL reference->Concepts->Sequences](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzsequences.htm)

[IBM i 7.2->Database->Reference->SQL reference->Statements->CREATE SEQUENCE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcsequence.htm)

[IBM i 7.2->Database->Reference->SQL reference->Language elements->Expressions->Sequence reference](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzseqref.htm)

Comment: Hi CRPence,
Thank you for your answer, but it not a merely sequential number. The sequence depends on input parameters, as it is a complex system for documents numbering.
Anyway, I managed to fulfill my purpose: I created an RPGLE service program without main, exported all functions, created a new SQL function which works everywhere SQL functions are allowed.
Full commands and specification can be provided if anyone needs them.
Thank you